# Thermodynamics transformation energy for a conservative system

Tags: thermodynamics

This is the link to the book. Pg11-13 are relevant.
http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks13/1305021p.pdf

I am reading "Thermodynamics" by Enrico Fermi. I don't understand how he derived equation 13 and $$L=-L_A+L_B$$.

Why does the system perform $-L_A$ and $L_B$ amount of work for two transformations on Page 13 (A->O and O->B)?
Shouldn't the system perform $L_A$ amount of work to transform from A to O because it takes $-L_A$ amount of work to transform from O to A?

Answer (score 1):

I find the presentation hard to follow and, as you will see at the end of my post below, it does not make sense to me when he reaches equation 13.

Start with eq 11.

$$U_{B}-U_{A}=-L$$

The author states *"$-L$ is the work performed by the external forces during a transformation from the initial state A to the final state B"*. He identifies $U$ as the energy of the system. If work is done *on the system* by external forces, as the author states, then clearly that work has to cause an increase in the energy of the system, i.e., $U_{B}-U_{A}>0$. For that to be true, the sign of $L$ would have to be negative. That would be consistent with the following version of the first law for a closed system (no mass transfer)

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Where work $W$ is positive if work is done by the system (reducing internal energy) and negative if done on the system (increasing internal energy). The author then makes the following statement:

*"From this equation it follows that the work, $L$, performed during
the transformation depends only on the extreme states A and B of the
transformation and not the particular way in which the transformation
from A to B is performed"*

Clearly, this means that the transformation does not involved any heat transfer $Q$, such as an adiabatic transformation, otherwise the work done does depend on the particular way the transformation occurs (the path). In short, since the author makes no mention of heat, it appears the author is considering conservation of energy for a purely mechanical system, at least through page 13.

Equation 12

$$U_{o}=0$$

The author is arbitrarily setting $U_{o}$ as the system state where its energy is zero and calling it the "standard state", the starting point for subsequent transformations.

Equation 13

$$U_{A}=-L_A$$

He now states *"Let $L_A$ be the work performed *by the system* during this transformation"* (from the standard state), meaning the sign of $L_A$ is positive. ***The problem is, if the system starts in the standard state of zero energy, then it has no energy to be able to perform work.*** So equation 13 does not make sense to me.

I suppose I could have missed something here, but at this point since the presentation no longer makes sense to me, I can't go on. Perhaps someone else can make sense of it to both you and I.

Sorry I could not be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer including a response to the issue about zero energy raised in the earlier answer by Bob D.

I think Fermi defines $U_0$ as zero energy to have a true zero energy reference state.  I think Fermi requires $L_A$ and $L_B$ both be negative (you have to do work on the system to raise the energy from zero); that is, the system cannot do work from the reference state (system cannot have negative energy).

Even if $U_0$ is not zero I can obtain his result as follows. (1) $U_B - U_A$ = -L, by definition.  (2) $U_A - U_0 = -L_A$. (3) $U_B - U_0 = -L_B$. Subtracting (2) from (3) we have (4) $U_B - U_A = -L_B + L_A$.  Comparing (4) to (1) we have $-L = -L_B + L_A%$ or $L = L_B - L_A$.